# can I run .shtml page as php with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cpanel

I need to put self updating year script in copyright footer of page for which I need to add this code
<?php echo date("Y"); ?>
to 404.shtml page and then, I tried to turn shtml page run as php with following code in htaccess file but it gives 500 Internal Server Error. Can anybody help in this regard?

```
application/x-httpd-php .shtml .html .htm
```

Comment: This is possible, you need to add php as _handler_ of that file type. But it is a very bad idea, since you configure a surprising behaviour of your server which might break other implementations. Instead, why don't you store that footer script as php file using the extension `.php` and reconfigure the error handler to that instead of the standard file? That would be more elegant and more secure.

Comment: better sense prevailed and I used javascript on 404.shtml file to display current year in copyright statement.. anyway thanks for answer and help.. God Bless